# Error showing on console when added nonce Content security policy php header

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers, content-security-policy, nonce

I am implementing a Content Security Policy on a WordPress website. I am using the following header-method in PHP to implement a Content Security Policy:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https: data:; script-src 'self' https: data: 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa'; style-src 'self' https: data: 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa' ");
```

And in the HTML code, the inline Script ans Style tags are like:-

```
<script nonce="EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa" type="text/javascript"> 
    // some code
</script>

<style nonce="EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa" type="text/css"> 
    // some code
</style >
```

And after page load we can see lot of console error
[image]

What would be the issue? is the provided Content security policy header are in the right order?

Answer (score 0):

First of all nonces should change on every pageload and should not be static. If the style source is static, a hash would be better.

Based on your console errors there seems to be two sources: modernizr script adding styles and inline styles present in the main page document. Modernizr should be modernized or thrown out, as the script is not CSP friendly. You may or may not be able to fix this with hashes, but that might not work well in all browsers.

The other source is the main page document. It could be an inline style, a style attribute or code injecting a style. Style attributes are not nonceable, but could be hashable with 'unsafe-hashes', but this is not supported in all browsers. You should identify the styles and rewrite them.